# Who was that guy in the final scene of Everybody Hates Chris?

Tags: character, ending, everybody-hates-chris

This character appears in the final scene of *Everybody Hates Chris*:

[image]

The camera lingers on him for a while and Chris also watches him for a moment.

Is he in anyway relevant or notable, or is it just a *Sopranos* reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a cameo by *Everybody Hates Chris* director Lev L. Spiro.** [He directed six episodes in all](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002973/). This was his only cameo on the show (as 'Ominous Man') according to IMDb and he's not a character. Seems it was just a fun cameo as a stand-in for the [Members Only Jacket Guy](http://sopranos.wikia.com/wiki/Man_in_Members_Only_Jacket) in the *Sopranos* finale, which this finale indeed parodizes. Crew cameos in finales are [quite common](http://www.vulture.com/2015/05/mad-men-crew-cameos-in-the-final-season.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The entire final scene is [a reference to the final scene of *The Sopranos*](http://www.tvworthwatching.com/post/CW-Everybody-Hates-Chris-Deserves-Reprieve-for-its-Sopranos-Cliffhanger.aspx):

> Series creators Chris Rock (the real, grown-up one) and Ali LeRoi
>   didn't stop there. Other Sopranos touches abounded. **A menacing guy sat
>   at the counter, looking over at their table.** Chris' dad Julius (Terry
>   Crews) had trouble parking his newspaper truck outside, just as Meadow
>   had a problem with her parallel parking on The Sopranos.

This video compares both:

Comment: As I stated in the question, is there anyway he's notable besides as a mere reference?